# Save canvas on server with node.js (or alternative)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas

Im trying to implement a feature on a hosted platform which does **not allow PHP**. Only JS & HTML. And Im stuck!

I have built this canvas which allows your to draw and then save via `document.getElementById("canvasimg")`

I want that image to somehow be saved onto the server and get re-called when a new user visit, so they will see what has been last saved on the canvas.

I was thinking to have a hosted file that get over-wrote when the user saves a new version of the canvas. Then that image can get called into the canvas as a background image to allow the next person to continue drawing on it?

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }

    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="500px" height="675px" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid;background:url(http://files.cargocollective.com/715286/sticker.jpg);background-size:100%100%;"></canvas>
        <div style="position:relative;top:40px;left:600px;">Eraser</div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:100px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:black;border:2px solid;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;">Pen</div>
        <img id="canvasimg" style="position:relative;top:10%;left:600px;" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:relative;top:150px;left:594px;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:relative;top:180px;left:550px;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

If you can't modify the server (e.g. PHP) then you certainly won't be able to use NodeJS.

The only thing you can do is save the canvas to `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` but those are temporary.